# git post-receive not executed

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

I have setup the following post-receive:

```
$ cat .git/hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/env sh
git checkout -f
```

which is executable:

```
$ l .git/hooks/post-receive
-rwx--x--x 1 nils nils 30 11. Jan 13:17 .git/hooks/post-receive
```

So when I push into it from my local machine it should checkout and have the changes I made locally. But that is not the case:

Local:

```
$ cat > testfile
hello world

$ git add testfile && git commit -m "added testfile" && git push production master
[master 9f5232d] added testfile
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 testfile
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 290 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://[…]/
   88ce501..9f5232d  master -> master
```

Afterwards on the remote machine:

```
$ git status --short
 D testfile
```

So it does not have the testfile in its working tree

```
$ git checkout -f 

$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Any Ideas what could be possibly wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should set the [GIT_WORK_TREE](http://gitmanual.org/git.html#_environment_variables) to be sure the checkout is done in the right place:

```
#!/bin/env sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/website.org git checkout -f
```

Do not forget to `chmod +x` the script and be sure that the user pushing has the rights to run the checkout command.